# Prevent textOutput from producing line break

Tags: r, shiny, line, break, shinydashboard

I build an application with shinydashboard and try to produce a box with (reactive) text. My code in dashboardBody is

```
box("Species was found in ", textOutput("Count1"), "of", Count2, "Sites")
```

Count1 is reactive and based on User Input in the UI. Count2 is defined in global.R.

The Output is:

```
Species was found in
1
of 134 Sites
```

So, how do I remove the line breaks? paste() isn't working since it only shows the html code of the textoutput Element.

Comment: I think using `paste` does what you want: `box(paste("Species was found in", textOutput("Count1"), "of", Count2, "Sites"))`

Comment: As I wrote paste() produces:
`Species was found in <div id="Count1" class="shiny-text-output"></div> of 134 Sites`

Comment: The `cat( )` function may be helpful here.

Comment: Nope, that produces: `ERROR: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat' `

Comment: Does `textOutput("Count1", inline = TRUE)` do the trick for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments it did work, so here my solution as an answer:

```r
box("Species was found in ", textOutput("Count1", inline = TRUE), "of", Count2, "Sites")
```

Without `inline = TRUE` it puts the `textOuput()`in a `div`, so that creates the line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping every element should work:

```
box(
    div(style="display: inline-block;","Species was found in "), 
    div(style="display: inline-block;",textOutput("Count1")), 
    div(style="display: inline-block;",paste("of", Count2, "Sites"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it also worked but I guess the solution @ek-g is a bit cleaner for me.